# Chosen Validation in Magento

Tags: jquery, validation, magento, prototype

I'm using the Chosen jQuery/Prototype plugin to replace select fields within Magento. Magento already has a validation system, written in prototype, in place. Unfortunately, the two do not play nice. Whenever chosen is used, the validation is completely ignored.

I've tried doing manual jquery validation, but its not working. What I have so far:

```
$j(".input-box select").chosen(function(){
        $j(this).each(function(){

            $j(this).addClass('required-entry product-custom-option')

        });

}).change( opConfig.reloadPrice() );
```

Unfortunately when the user clicks the add to cart button, it just continues on ignoring the above.

I'd like to tie Chosen into the validation system that is already in place. Here is the Magento Validation file:

http://demo.magentocommerce.com/js/prototype/validation.js

and here is a page where you can test the validation (click add to cart without chosing any product options):

http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalog/product/view/id/119/s/coalesce-functioning-on-impatience-t-shirt/category/4/

EDIT: Here is the actual code that is listed under the Magento Product Page: http://pastie.org/2599676

Comment: Do you see in your firebug, does chosen's hidden select has needed validation classes? It is very hard to suggest something without looking at your page.

Comment: I wish I could show you, but it's local and Magento isn't the easiest to move. Chosen does not have the validation class, but when I manually apply it still no luck.

Comment: Does your "Add to cart" button has `onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"`? Could you change productAddToCartForm.submit() source code (for example, in firebug) - add alert there and see whether it is really invoked?

Comment: I removed it, and it no longer does anything. I'd assume in the prototype validation that is where it fires the validation for the product options, correct? I think the major issue is Chosen does not have the same markup (<select> vs <ul><li><a>) and so the validation is looking for the <select> tag and we are using the Chosen "replacement" markup. Maybe there is a way to change what the validation looks for?

Comment: No, you are wrong. Look at that page on the demo store. And look with firebug on your page with chosen, you will see hidden select near ul.

Comment: Correct, I see the hidden <select> and it does have the validation set up, but it will not validate when "nothing" is selected, like Magento does default. I will edit the post to show my full code.

Comment: I looked into http://pastie.org/2599676, bith selects have needed validation classes. But where is add to cart button? Does it have `onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"`?

Comment: Correct, it does have the onclick function

Comment: refer to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/integrating-chosen-js-prototype-or-jquery/63758#63758 for a working integration solution

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get this working without modifying anything but css code. For some reason prototype/magento validation is checking to see whether the select element is visible, and won't do any validation if it's not. It only actually checks the style attribute though, so first a little jQuery:

`$('.product-view select').removeAttr('style');`

Then fix that with css:

`.product-view select {
        display: none !important;
    }`

This introduces a few hiccups, you will need to explicitly set the width on the chosen element. Also the validation error message will be above the chosen container, so set the parent element to position relative and add:

`.product-view .chzn-container {
        width: 140px !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }`

to put everything in order.